# How to Reload a page from Iframe?

Tags: php, html, iframe

Iam just using an iframe for login and register.
and i need to reload the page when the message appears that he successfully registered/logged-in.

for example the iframe would be

when he click login in the iframe it reload other page called "login_success" this page send message"successfully logged in".

Now is the proplem i need the browser reload the page so that the session work in the page that loads the Iframe.

Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 4):

You can use following script.

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

Comment: I had seen this code before but i don't know how to use it

Comment: Give me sample script please. so that i understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
document.getElementById('ifarme_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

If it is in same domain you can try below

```
var myframe = document.getElementById('Ifrme_id');
myframe.src = myframe.src;
```